# Is $T$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:P_2(\Re)\to P_2(\Re)$ be defined by $T(a+bx+cx^2)=b-2cx+ax^2$. Is $T$ invertible? If yes, find the inverse of $T$.

I plugged in the standard ordered basis and got $\{\{0,1,0\},\{0,0,2\},\{1,0,0\}\}$. I know that this matrix is invertible, however I do not see how it helps me find the inverse of $T$.

Comment: What is $P2(R)?$

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to format it properly, it is the transformation from the vector space of polynomials of degree 2 or less to the same vector space.

Answer (score 1):

What $T$ does to the standard basis, gives you a formula for the matrix associated to $T$.  The vectors that the basis map to give you the columns.  For the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ I get $T(1)=x^2$, $T(x)=1$, $T(x^2)=-2x$.  As vectors these are $(0,0,1)$, $(1,0,0)$, and $(0,-2,0)$.  These are the columns of the matrix.  Now invert the matrix. The inverse matrix will give you the inverse transformation.

Comment: The inverse of this matrix gives T^(-1)?

Answer (score 0):

Is there really the need to calculate any matrix?  Obviously $T^{-1}(a+bx+cx^2)=c+ax-\frac 12 bx^2$.

Edit a missing $b$ in front of $x^2$.

Comment: I do not understand why would this be so obvious.. could you please explain a bit more :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik  Well, consider $T$ as a sort of permutation.  It sends the first coefficient to the third, the second to the first and the third to the negative double of the second.  And $T^{-1}$  reverses the sendings: third to first, first to second and second to the negative half of third coefficient.